# raspivid option -n together with ‐awb or -ev

Tags: camera

When I run `raspivid` with `-n` option I cannot use options `-awb` and `-ev` does not work either. My goal is to use camera in `greyscale` mode without a preview window.

When I tested with `-ev off` then video was black, but I won't see any differences in other `-ev` modes.

If I run `raspivid` **with** preview window and with option `-awb off` then picture is in greyscale and also saved video isin  greyscale.

Maybe someone has useful info about `-awb` and `-n` option together. Is this a limitation of software or hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for grey scale use the saturation command sa -100 . Im using RaspiVid 1.3.3 using the command raspivid -t 12000 -n -sa -100 -awb off -o output.mp4 works fine with no preview for my 512mb model B Pi

When you say -ev off do you mean -ev -10
with raspivid -t 12000 -n -awb off -ev -10 -o output.mp4 I got a colour image

If you mean -ex off then raspivid -t 12000 -n -awb off -ex off -o output.mp4 give a colour images as well. Im not getting any black images.

raspivid -t 12000 -n -sa -100 -awb off -ex -off -o output.mp4 give a greyscale image with no preview fine.