# raspivid with awb off gives black image

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspivid

I want to turn off auto white balance for my raspivid stream. However, when doing that, the image turns completely black. Why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the official forums I got the answer. I need to set red and blue gains in the awbg parameter: `-awbg '1.0,1.0'`.

The parameters of course can be tweaked to give the desired appearance.

The answer is actually hidden in the official documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another question/answer similar to this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10279/raspivid-option-n-together-with-awb-or-ev) that seems to fix an issue like yours.  Maybe that fits your situation?  If so, please let us know.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Yes, I know that question. Did not help. I have tried `-awb off -ex off -sa -10` and different combinations. I think it is very weird that turning awb off messes at all with the exposure.

Comment: I also tried to use `-awbg X` to set the awb gains. But I get an error that the option is not known. Google indicates this is a common problem...